# Can I verify token in reducer without violating React design principles?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to figure out the structure of my jwt token authentication with react/redux. The way I have it set up now, I use a middleware that saves the token in localstorage when the action ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS is dispatched (Note: The security of localstorage is besides the point).

For the initial state of whether the user is logged in, I currently get the token from local storage and verify it inside of my login reducer. My question is whether or not that is a place that I should indeed put that logic.

jwt-handler middleware for saving token:

```
import {ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS} from "./dataTypes/login"

const jwtHandler = store => next => action => {

    switch(action.type){
        case ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            const token = action.payload;

            localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    }

    return next(action);
}

export default jwtHandler;
```

Login reducer (code in question is from the top to the initial state):

```
import {
    ATTEMPT_LOGIN_BEGIN, ATTEMPT_LOGIN_FAIL, ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS
} from "../dataTypes/login";

import authenticateToken from "./authenticateToken";

const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
const isValid = authenticateToken(token); //Decodes and checks date to ensure valid

if(!isValid){
    localStorage.setItem("token", "");
}

const initialState = {
    loading:false,
    errorMessage: "",
    success:false,
    isLoggedIn: isValid
};

const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ATTEMPT_LOGIN_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading:true,
                errorMessage:""
            };
        case ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading:false,
                success:true,
                token:action.payload
            };
        case ATTEMPT_LOGIN_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading:false,
                errorMessage:action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default loginReducer;
```

I feel like there may be a better place to put my is logged in logic, but I have yet to find a good answer online.

Comment: if you you use redux-thunk you can do the logic there e.g localstorage

Comment: I do have thunk. That is where I do the logic for setting the token in local storage. I'm just not sure how I would implement the logic there for getting the token from storage.

Comment: Let me correct myself. I am using thunk, but my set token logic is not using it. Instead, I have that logic inside of custom middleware. How would you go about using thunk for my purposes?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer your middleware pattern, but bit more centralised:

**NOTE**: this is opinionated and just an example sketch

```
// middleware.js
import {
    INIT_SESSION, ATTEMPT_LOGIN_BEGIN, ATTEMPT_LOGIN_FAIL, ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGOUT
} from "../dataTypes/login";

import authenticateToken from "./authenticateToken";

const jwtHandler = store => next => action => {

    switch(action.type){
        // INIT_SESSION handled only here not in any reducer
        case INIT_SESSION:
            const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            const isValid = authenticateToken(token);
            if(valid){
            store.dispatch({type:ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: token});
            } else {
             localStorage.removeItem("token");
            }
            break;

        case ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            const newToken = action.payload;
            localStorage.setItem("token", newToken);
           break;
        case LOGOUT:
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
           break;
        default:

    }

    return next(action);
}

export default jwtHandler;


// index.js
    const store = createStore();
    store.dispatch({type: INIT_SESSION});

    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>//...


// reducer.js stays clean...
```

Answer (score -2):

In your reducer you can do

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    // ...data
    loading:false,
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ATTEMPT_LOGIN_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        case ATTEMPT_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                token: action.payload.token,
            };
        case ATTEMPT_LOGIN_FAILURE:
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                token: null,
            };
     }
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't reducers be pure?